# Request-URI Too Large showing on server

Tags: php

I am passing the following data through url :

```
<?php    
   $url = "generate_pdf.php/?feed=" . urlencode(serialize($result));    
   echo '<div id="left-sidebar">';
   echo '<a href="' . $url . '"><div id="pdf">Download PDF</div></a>';
   echo '</div>';
?>
```

Here the `$result` containing the rss feed data in form of array. I am using `urlencode(serialize($result)` for passing that data through url and its working perfectly on local machine but in server it showing the following error :

```
Request-URI Too Large
The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.
```

Please tell me your views to deal with this problem.

Comment: It's because you are using the GET method which has a length limit (255 chars if I'm not mistaken). Send the serialized data as POST.

Comment: I want to send that data through href url

Comment: To bad, it's a limit/rule. It will need to be via POST. You can make a link/button that submit a form and send all data as a POST-request. (formname.submit() )

Comment: Regardless of what you **want** - you can't. You have to use the POST method.

Comment: OK..Thanks...but my question is how its working on my localhost if its rule of 255 chars length.

Comment: Servers and browsers can be configured to accept variable-width URLs. For security reasons (mostly), nearly everything I worked with had a limit for GET method and it was at 255 chars. It's also not a good idea to send so much data via GET method, the URL will be totally impractical, plus sending serialized data via URL that user can modify is a bad idea. What Alvaro said in his answer is the preferred method of passing data around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this mistake (It was more than not knowing than making a mistake!) once. I've build an ajax engine for webapps. It used only the get method. Once I had a form with a lot of data and it did not work.

After some research I found out this: [look here](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html)

So basically most browser does not make any problems because they support approximately 100.000 characters. But most web-servers like Apache only support 4000 characters from a URL.

No you can not just configure Apache to accept more. It is possible do but you have to edit the source code to do so.

**solution:** Use the POST method it is made for large data transfer between web-servers and clients(which are most likely browsers).

In your case I think you want to create a pdf with some user input an for some reason that input is larger than 4000 characters.

Comment: I am wondering why generate the URL on server side? You could store your data in database or json an then give a key to the link witch is used to get the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

1. Store data somewhere on the server (e.g. a database)
2. Assign a unique ID to such data
3. Pass that ID in the URL
4. Retrieve data from storage using the ID as key