# How to send and receive an encoded string image from server?

Tags: android, android-image

In my application i have to select an image from gallery and set it as an profile picture. For that i have encoded the image as string and send it to the server.While receiving response from the server it shows the following error

**`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">`**

```
<html><head>
<title>414 Request-URI Too Long</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request-URI Too Long</h1>
<p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.<br /></p><hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 Server at localhost Port80</address></body></html>
```

To convert the image as a string i have used the below code:

```
profileimage.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bm = profileimage.getDrawingCache();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImage = null;
            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Please help me to fix the error.

URL:

```
http://192.168.1.18/fl_api/registration/ghh/fgh/8d509c28896865f864f328f30f15721/5698742315/dfg@g.com/What was the name of your first best friend from childhood/dgg/-9j-4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD-2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH-2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH-wAARCACgAHgDASIAAhEBAxEB-8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL-8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6-8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL-8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6-9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD-AD-6KKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAPs-4d-s9-Dfxvq4tG1jxhFaCFGLxXWkwsZhueaM3lz4ae2iSKKG5Yu0bNiCV3RSI4n5f4t-BDwb4D8eaD4d0LV-EF7o94uix6nNqVxpUurQXWpK8x8qKz022FqZIRiGxubSW8iZVluCRc20FfVXwE8J6rpeu+ItL1fStR0m83aXLDPcwPHHZtbx+JIHkguxvjEU807Lb3djKVcR+ZaSD7M8i-Pv7SkOrS-FnxO5YiTT7jS7XyGnAuprbStG0g211bNNHBK8mC-lGMSl7WK2+eYCS4n+QwmNxs8ynReLcqSo+6puLTm04qWiSu27p66qOjVz7PHZZh8HRmvq9KtKHLUU6KveHtE76N3i42Uox1Sk0pNxs-BfAnwu1Lx94otPDmlGQLJcxx32oMy+Rp9p5oE95KPJJfyogSkOUaWYxxCQF8j7j1H9h34fPbyJo-ivxjDeSwhbV7+40C7t7e6Z50jNzBb6HYS3aMRARbxzWrFi0f2vdJuj9j-Zy+ETeBfC-9qatam28QeKs6pf28iu50qyka5ksNGBRH-0hIPLkvwPKLX0ps7ljBafax75cyopktjKxjGXdnuGAeQERKkr2scsjRw-u7i7eSWOVWa3eSVbSYyP9JTnUrS92Xwdtno1zSummm+nwrTTdnznsadOClOLfNJacrejc2lF2utLXvrpPVqNl+I-jv4MeL-h3dSpr+m3J08SiK21uyD3Gj3RYMYyl2bWMwSShGdLW9itrsojyLC8OJq87XTbdhgPNuyAFLIN-UZXMXAJ24DHODnJJAr9xtbtYLu28qeC2g3yvCsF1PbobmNht-wBHnSU2d7FMHzG1xJbvJbgedBHOZSniWu-AjwBqdw7S+BtNguSytEun2l7payEtLK6S22iyxRO6RyEtKC4dNnkiGVGNbqq4vlqU3vZSgk01dW5d3LbXTZtbsx+qe05nSrwaTSamnFxbb0l8kul991K5+VcWi+aW2JckLlScpxICRg5iBwAMk47gdQTXunwu-Z61Hx5r2j6fqr6ho1hqV9ZWu5fsv9oPDPcKk9xFFNGUhhhti14s86mOSIJsV45Umr9GvBv7LGsQ+X-Y3w5itbhSJlvtQtFsmWO4YBkTUdXP2ib90HYpDKWKlGASGYtXv-gX4DXPgPxDYah4k1TSZbmMyS20Ok2Wu6mZbt4722tss2mQmziaCZpJUV32TpbeYFG27fOVWpKLVOm72Svu7q95JW0tZpu6WsLptGlPCU4K9aum1y3jbT7dld2vflTsndpvd6n47-Hb4A6Z8LfF1zY6Fea5e+FZJPK0zVdVewuLkzxIPtdnfT2FhZwJcwt88e21RZ7c+bCrNHdrH4mvhvStp3TXpkBK7VltwMhsZBa1ywI4XaCM4y4LBa-cjxB8HdB1fUdcfxNe397ZavdRyf2PfafoWkwu97fRpaBtP8RXNzqVwTfTwrZAolx9tktkhdZbhRJ5Nb-ss-A2x1ObUrqw16+tgJ7AeHrvWNWh0qPUM3UCRf2hYLp9zJqDTQyWcFs2vm0kvZIrWS08ySytzu6cowV6i+Bc19JqWl9OW8k7Xi9Oi-mchQpKU2lGWkbXjLk95u+nNdWtZcqk3pqm9fydsvBlpf3MFlZpq17e3EnlQ2VksdxdTStu8uO3ijs5JJ5MKW8uNGZgCABndW7pnwj1-Xbu707RfDnim8vLGRIb5HsxbRWEzAt5F-Pc2kMVnM0bRPHHcPGXBI3Bmj3frZpPgH4c+F4Zb-wn8P8ATNPnnhktEvZBbRs9xA-lrpl-dX09w1nePMluk8mq+TsvZUshK3iCGbShbeXSYkgivmg0FruIS2MOpvp+lxXxkuR5Udhbz3KSzSFrlT5aQ71llEchS5juFSqfIn79RtJpaq32ZvX3W7vTt9lu+xnKLatGFOOr95Q5nZJaq7td27Ne89bx1-JTXPgf4s8OW0N7q+j6jDZSxFzd209lqFvAwuBCRdy2KzraZLKE+0+Ukjb1hllZHUc3D4ItJ8JFLevK7xwxIstszGeVwsaiJLd5H37ZI1VfmMwCZ3gI-wCzN3ot7HK8VpCls9sqwzSPZyloFltTdr+-uz9mFrHHbyxzyj+0HW4kaCa1jCMg4cxfDjw4ssMOlaPZ61Nc+SdT8NaLox1iwiu0t3Z7kx2sSXJneaOV7iFYrdkRDIyWodkcuXW04QVlZtNyvzOztZNq1r303d+pNBQjGTq05Ts4++2lBJ8-xNq8b8trLmbaaScr3-K3TvhZq2tXVxa6Dpmu61LbxmSWHTdPvLuWJUmeFzItrply2NyBuUVl3MhUtGSxX7W+HtC0zVZHtvDvi628YzXUtrFPb6JeaRZ6vYQfZnln1RbNL4S3EKyNAJmimvXEisLKynIuACu2lg1KHNUqOLai01RcoyTb1i41UrWafW6v7zSMXOlJtwT5dFaM72lzJNNSp80fJPXlkrt8qb5T4UeHNdu9OF1rmlWkF1bXfn2ktnPDMNVNvYHT1ea8hLtImLmG3+xGC2uI1064t5F2XaTr5Z4M+Fmp-E39o74n+Pdagni8JeG-FDabp0M7Ryx614q0HTrXS7i5gaNrmOXTdOuNP+0SSLPGst19msmZpbbU7Qdro3jjRvh9oFkbzxQn9g6FaWuky6vdR7p7hN8xuIdNUAC61DXTbRsqwrdq8dw1ssAazeaT6JtPGGn32nz6-p11bRDWbdNRsLuSOZbfy5lKQme1lmTZNZRoJri2d4pRcK8DKskTRr+Y5HFTxeKlyN01CMVUafKnzxlZJrSTUWuXVxi3dq6PtM1xE6cKfLNQaavTTd4w1Tu+aUuRO-vSb5nK1248z1LTwxfML230nTbu+YFEMOnwNPGZJpCFZnitZ1htxMQGuGaNIlEru6qFlPSaV8C-F9-5v9o3GnaNbQuwnN1LJfXoKszi5j0uJpraNZpjcG1Frq9pdWsUllDdMJo1tz6b8H-ifa+O9Nbw5qgt9P8AFehB47+zsf
```

Code to upload an image:

```
public class PickGalleryImageActivity extends Activity implements
        OnClickListener {

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    private ImageView profileimage = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        profileimage .setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (v.getId() == R.id.imageView) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }



    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

             profileimage  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
             profileimage .setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }
```

}

Code for server call:

```
public class ServerCommunication {
    String msg;
    String url;
    static DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    public String makeServiceCall(String url, final Context context) {
        this.url = url;

        try {

            if (!isConnected(context)) {

                return url;
            }
            if (isConnected(context) == false) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No Connection Available", 500).show();
            }


            URI uri = new URI(url.replace(" ", "%20"));
            Log.d("uri", url + "");

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);


            HttpParams httpParameters = httppost.getParams();

            int timeoutConnection = 100000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                    timeoutConnection);

            int timeoutSocket = 100000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            /* Checking response */
            if (response != null) {
                msg = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            }
            Log.d("serverResponse", msg);
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, 500).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return msg;

    }

    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which method you are using get or post.Generally this error comes when get method is being used .

Comment: @user3349843 then may be its related to your server settings not from application.see this https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Long+URLs+Are+Rejected+by+Apache+with+'Request-URI+Too+Large'+Error

Comment: I have sent the request using POST method only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816359/request-uri-too-large-showing-on-server @user3349843

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha is that a server problem?

Comment: @user3349843 if your are using post method then may be it is .But make sure you are using POST method .Also I have post a link of similar question you can get hint  from there

Comment: it seems you are sending a long data in your Url but in post data is not get  attached with Url

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha yeah am using POST method. Even i have checked in RESTClient debugger it shows success result.

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha "post data is not get attached with Url" i couldn't get you.Could you explain?

Comment: @user3349843 Can you post your code here through which you are uploading image ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp refer this for post /get differences

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha i have post the code. Review it

Comment: @user3349843 code of file uploading??

Comment: the above code is to upload image from the gallery.

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha i have also updated with server communication code

Comment: @user3349843  I think you should try the format one that is posted in answer below .Thats proper way of using post method as per my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
try{
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", imageString));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Country", "country name"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
httpclient.execute(httppost);
}catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: But he is using post method only

Answer (score 0):

Use the Post method to send data to server, When you convert bitmap to ImageString that string is to long for URL. So use POST method to request the server, that will work.

Like that: It is sending Post request as a josn, you can use your own string entity

```
public static String callWebService(String value, String urlString) {
            String responseString = "";
    try {
        // make web service connection
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(urlString);
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        // Build JSON string
        JSONStringer TestApp = new JSONStringer().object().key("imageString").value(value);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(TestApp.toString());

        Log.d("****Parameter Input****", "Testing:" + TestApp);
        request.setEntity(entity);
        // Send request to WCF service
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        responseString = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());  

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseString = e.getMessage();
    }

    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: I have used above code for posting images to server, Make sure you are setting correct params.

Comment: In post method your url should be like that http://192.168.1.18/fl_api/registration, pointing to your webpage, and other params should be set in post request.setEntity method.